# Trying to Run MessageBoxA()(#include<windows.h> method in different Way in c++

Tags: c++

I am Making Library Management System in C++.My Problem is whenever I invoke 
getFName() member function and if user enter incorrect first_name(containing 123,%@ etc) the Validate() function will return true and MessageBoxA()(in windows.h header file) will be invoked but i have two problem :

1) If I press Enter key than MessageBox should be gone but it cannot.It require the mouse click on OK button. How to use Enter key in this problem instead of mouse click ?

2) If user press any alphanumeric key than it will count as next first_name in the presence of MessageBox.

My expected output is if MessageBox is displayed than user should not allowed enter  the first_name until it press OK button in MessageBox() function.

```
void Person :: getFName()
{
    Again :
      cout<<endl<<"Enter Your First Name : ";
      getline(cin,F_Name);
      if(Validate(F_Name))
        {
     int ch = MessageBoxA(NULL,"InValid First Name","C++Error",MB_OK);
         goto Again;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int ch = MessageBoxA(GetConsoleWindow(),"InValid First Name","C++Error",MB_OK);
```

This should make the message box modal in respect to the console window and not allow any input into it.

Comment: Getting Error GetConsoleWindow() was not declared in this scope

Comment: @HarshJoshi, that's strange, it should be there as long as you've included `Windows.h`, which I assume you did since you are using `MessageBoxA`.

Comment: Yes i have included #include<windows.h> file

Comment: @HarshJoshi, try including `Wincon.h`.

Comment: @HarshJoshi, try adding `#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500` before including `Windows.h`.

Comment: _@r3musn0x_ Unless @HarshJoshi decides to put a [mcve] in their question as required here, this would probably continue endlessly.

Comment: @HarshJoshi, OK, there is something weird with your Windows SDK, you can try to declare it yourself as a last resort but that's not normal: `extern "C" HWND WINAPI GetConsoleWindow();`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I'm afraid no MCVE will allow us to understand why OP's `Windows.h` doesn't declare this function.

Comment: @r3musn0x I don't even see that `#include <Windows.h>` was done properly in the OP's question.